# App is not asking for Photo Library usage permission

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, swift4, photolibrary

I have added **Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description** & **Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description**.

[image]

But none of the keys is asking for user permission to access the photo library.

I have tested in Simulator as well as in real device.

I even tried by adding a single key at a time. Like only **Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description** or **Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description**. And also tried by adding both the keys together.

But none of the above scenarios is working for me.

I also added **Privacy - Camera Usage Description** and that's working perfectly fine. But photo library usage is not asking for user's permission

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Note from Apple:**
>
> When using the UIImagePickerController to bring up the user's photo library, your > app doesn't need to request permission explicitly.

After iOS 10, if your app is using `PHAsset, PHPhotoLibrary, and PHImageManager`, then you need to include `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` in app's Info.plist file.

Detail info is available here: [apple-ref-documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/requesting_authorization_to_access_photos)